# Submit+html+Enter

Tags: html, jquery, submit

На форме несколько полей `input` и несколько кнопок `submit`.
При вводе текста в любом из `input` и нажатии на `enter` постоянно срабатывает событие `click` первой кнопки. Как сделать чтобы срабатывало это событие второй или третьей кнопки.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>  
 <head>  
 <title></title>    
 </head>  
 <body>  
  <form action="index.php" method="post">
  Название вашей компании: </br>
 <input name="Name_company" type="text" value="<?php echo $name;?>"></br>
 Город: </br>
<input name="City_company" type="text" value="<?php echo $city;?>"></br>
<input type="submit" name="Change_Sele" onclick="ChangeSelect('<?php echo $per; ?>'); return false;" id="visibleCat" value="OK" > 
    <span id="spanDelete" style="display: none;">При изменении категории вся информация из поля "Дополнительно" будет удалена</span>
<input type='submit' onclick='Update(".$per."); return false;' id='myForm' value='Сохранить'><span id='dvloader'></span>
 <input type="submit" value="Удалить эту компанию" name="deletecompany" onclick="Deletecompany('<?php echo $per; ?>'); return false;">
```

Comment: HTML код покажите пожалуйста. Без него сложно понять суть проблемы.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Comment: @Александр что то ерунда какая то, кнопка отправки `submit` может быть только одна у формы, закостылить это можно с помощью `js` вручную при вводи `enter` вызывать клик по кнопкам. Но логику тогда придется писать самому, какую кнопку именно нужно вызывать. Либо блокировать отправку по `enter` и пускай пользователь на кнопки жмет в ручную, это более правильный вариант

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, почему только одна? Может быть и несколько.

Comment: Блин))) Ну вот вы мне и помогли сами того наверно не понимая)))) Я оказывается не знал разницы между тегом submit и тегом button. Спасибо!

Comment: @Streletz работать будет только первая по нажатию на `enter`. Тут нужно только блокировать отправку на `enter` из полей, иначе ни как. Либо переходить на `<button></button>`

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, если просто по клавише Enter, то да. Если нажимать руками или обрабатывать события onkeydown, то может быть сколько угодно.

Comment: @Streletz я же отвечаю на вопрос, а не придумываю условия. В вопросе стоит `по нажатию на enter`, я и написал, кнопка отправки может быть только одна. Это и ежу понятно что кнопок может быть сколько угодно ;) Хотя не понятно что вы там хотите на `onkeydown` обрабатывать.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант.

Обработать событие `onkeydown` у input'а или нескольких.

В обработчике события нужно сделать проверку, которая будет определять, что нажата именно клавиша `Enter`. Если это действительно так, просто вызываем `Click()` у нужного submit'а

Ниже приведён пример для верхнего input'a.

**JS:**

```
function checkKey(e) {
        var inp = document.getElementById('inp1');
        if(e.keyCode == "13") {
        var inp = document.getElementById('myForm');
        inp.click();
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input name="Name_company" onkeydown="checkKey(event)" type="text" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
```

В результате по нажатию Enter будет отрабатывать второй `submit`.